# Trying to set a custom typeface in navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation, typeface, drawer

I want to set a custom typeface in the navigation drawer, already searched the problem and didn't find any solution... Here's my NavigationDrawerAdapter.java where I want to set the custom typeface:

I also already tried NavigationDrawerFragment.java and my MainActivity.java but this also didn't work. As I could set a custom typeface in all other adapters, I tried to also do it there but it doesn't work...

```
public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private Object[] array;
private int resource;
private int textViewResourceId;
Activity a;
private Activity activity;


public NavigationDrawerAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, Object[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.array = objects;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
    }

    TextView row = (TextView) v.findViewById(textViewResourceId);
    row.setText((String) array[position]);

    TextView navtext = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer_text);
    Typeface tf = TypefaceUtil.getAndCache(activity, "Lato-Semibold.ttf");
    navtext.setTypeface(tf);


    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            row.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.btn_material_charts, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case 1:
            row.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.btn_material_search, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case 2:
            row.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.btn_material_my_music, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case 3:
            row.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.btn_material_radio, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case 4:
            row.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.btn_material_play, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case 5:
            row.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.btn_material_listening_local, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case 6:
            row.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.btn_material_news, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case 7:
            row.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.btn_material_settings, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case 8:
            row.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.btn_material_about, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
    }

    return row;
}
}
```

Comment: where you have added `Lato-Semibold.ttf` file in project. in assets/. or assets/../.. ?

Comment: **Never** use `LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`. **Always** use `getLayoutInflater()`, called on an `Activity`. Beyond that, you may wish to explain what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: The app crashes when I use the setTypeface code, if I remove this code part everything works fine.

Comment: "The app crashes when I use the setTypeface code" -- when you looked at your [Java stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this), what did you learn? If you cannot make sense of that stack trace, edit your question and paste the entire stack trace into it, alongside your source code.

Comment: I'm using Gradle, Android Studio doesn't work for my project. What should I do then?

Comment: LogCat is available via **`adb`**, the Android Debug Monitor (`tools/monitor` in your SDK), and Eclipse, as well as Android Studio.

Comment: I checked the logcat on my Android device and via ADB on my PC but I don't understand anything and I can't even copy it.. May I upload the APK to my Google Drive and you check?